# Which version of the JDK should we install for Cassandra 4.0.1

Tags: cassandra

We are planning to upgrade our Cassandra servers from 3.0.11 to 4.0.1
[Here](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html) it says to use JDK 8. I would like to know if as of this writing this is still the case. I believe the latest released Oracle version is JDK 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary version for Cassandra 4.0 is Java 8. The Java 11 is marked as experimental, but there was a [recent discussion](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-dev/202108.mbox/browser) of removing that label for 4.0.

But work on the Java 17 has started only recently, and it may not be supported for 4.0, but for newer major releases

Comment: Okay. So for a production environment you would recommend we use Java 8?

Comment: Most probably. Although look into mailing list, there were some people saying that they are using Java 11 in prod

Comment: Yes, seems like many support making 11 "non experimental"